# Plotting power function line in a double logarithmic axis plot R

Tags: r, logging, axes

I am having a problem plotting a power function line to a plot that has both axis on log scale. I need to keep the axis on the log scale. I don't want to log transform my data. That's why I am using  the `log="xy"` argument on the plot function as indicated below.

However, I haven't been able to add the power function to this plot. I've tried different ways so far, including the `nls` (below), but nothing seems to work.

Could anyone help me please?
Thank you,
Maíra

```
nls4=nls(Slope~i*CA^-z,start=list(i=0.1,z=-0.04),data=slpca1)
abline(nls4)
plot(Slope~CA,data=slpca1,xlab="Contributing area (ha)",ylab="Slope (m m[-1])",log="xy",
     xlim=c(0.001,1),ylim=c(0.01,1),xaxt="n",yaxt="n",cex.lab=2,cex.axis=1.5,
     cex=2,pch=16,family="serif") 
axis(side=1, at=(c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1)),labels=c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1)) 
axis(side=2,at=(c(0.01,0.1,1)),labels=c(0.01,0.1,1))
```

Comment: You appear to be rather confused as to how everything in `R` works.  Why are you plotting **after** drawing your `abline` ,and have you read `?plot` and `?par` to learn how to place multiple plots on a single graph?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get help here is to provide a completely reproducible example (you gave us your code, but you didn't provide the data for `slpca1`) and keep that example as simple as possible (no need for axis labels, fonts, etc. unless it's an elemental part of the question).

So, I created some fake data, fit your nonlinear regression, and plotted the resulting fit.  Hopefully this will help you get started, and you can make modifications as you wish.

```
# create some fake data so I can run your code
CA <- runif(20, 1, 20)
Slope <- 0.1*CA^-0.04 + rnorm(20, 0, 0.001)
slpca1 <- data.frame(CA, Slope)
rm(CA, Slope)

# fit a nonlinear regression
nls4 = nls(Slope ~ i*CA^-z, start=list(i=0.1,z=-0.04), data=slpca1)
# plot the observed values
plot(Slope~CA, data=slpca1, log="xy")
# plot the predicted line
ord <- order(slpca1$CA)
lines(slpca1$CA[ord], predict(nls4)[ord])
```